# Bat file - remove and copy

Tags: batch-file

I want to remove all directory content (subdirectories and files, but not the main directory).
After that I want to copy all content from other directory to that directory.
How could I do this?

This code doesn't work

```
cd C:\directory1
rmdir /s/q
pause

xcopy C:\directory2\directory22 C:\directory1 /s /e
```

Comment: Does it not work in some special fashion it's worth mentioning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rmdir needs a directory to delete, so this will work, but you will get an error message:

```
cd C:\directory1
rmdir . /s /q
pause

xcopy C:\directory2\directory22 C:\directory1 /s /e
```

But you can also do this:

```
cd C:\
rmdir C:\directory1 /s /q
md C:\directory1
pause

xcopy C:\directory2\directory22 C:\directory1 /s /e
```